# random SSD turn off - ext4_find_entry , reading directory lblock0

Tags: ext4, disk, ssd

From last 2 weeks I have problem with my SSD in GNU/Linux. I think it's not device problem but I'm not sure. 
From time to time (every 1-2 days last days) I loss physical access to the disk, as if it was disconnected or powered off.

The error:

```
EXT4-fs error (device: sda2): ext4_find_entry:1465: inode #1308161: comm NetworkManager: reading directory lblock 0
```

I've typed this error from photo so it can be not fully accurate.

Notes:

Device is always the same "sda2", haven't noticed error with other (big home) partition. I will try to check this next time.
Inode and process name changes but NetworkManager is quite common. lblock is always 0.

Hardware:

Dell E7270 with SSD disk LITEON CV3-8D512-11 SATA 512GB

Software:

Debian testing, kernel 4.11.

smartctl brief output:

```
Device Model:     LITEON CV3-8D512-11 SATA 512GB
Serial Number:    TW0956WWLOH006CU022Z
LU WWN Device Id: 5 002303 100ce15e0                                                                                                                                         
Firmware Version: T89110D                                                                                                                                                    
User Capacity:    512,110,190,592 bytes [512 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      M.2
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS, ATA/ATAPI-7 T13/1532D revision 4a
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Jul  5 12:32:39 2017 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

...

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       327
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       335
175 Program_Fail_Count_Chip 0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
176 Erase_Fail_Count_Chip   0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       59
178 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Chip  0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
180 Unused_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot 0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       2688
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       76
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
238 Unknown_Attribute       0x0003   097   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       3
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       4293005286
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       3510503294

SMART Error Log Version: 0
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%       298         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       294         -
# 3  Offline             Interrupted (host reset)      80%       294         -
# 4  Offline             Interrupted (host reset)      10%       294         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       294         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         1         -
# 7  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%         1         -
```

Ideas:

- run bad block check
- check connections

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I've fixed this by removing SDD, blowing air into M.2 connector and reinserting it back.

When I booted to rescue Debian from USB I've noticed more detailed kernel debug information. While searching I've noticed most solutions were to replace SATA cables. Laptop M.2 connection has no cables.

I'm posting screen
[image: screen]

Some most important log texts:

```
exception Emask 0x10 SAct ... SErr ... action 0xe frozen
interface fatal error, PHY RDY changed
SError: { PHYRdyChg LinkSeq }
failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
hard resetting link
```

Comment: In the end I've replaced SSD and it fixed the error :)

Comment: Meaning you think it was due to faulty hardware? I'm facing similar problems and not sure whether I should go through the hassle of returning the ssd or not, especially that it's my main drive.

Answer (score 3):

It's APST problem.

And there are two workarounds:

1. Run

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   ```

   Search for the line that begins with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and add as value `nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0`.

   The result should be:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0"
   ```

   Save the file then:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   reboot
   ```
2. If the first variant doesn't work, just disable ASPM:`pcie_aspm=off`.
   So the final result should be:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=off"
   ```

   Save the file then:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   reboot
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the reason causing your machine the above situation. But in my case, it was because my computer was near an electric cord. There may be some physical phenomena such as electromagnetic resonance or something that caused my machine to keep having APST problems. I rearranged my desk and did not place the laptop near the power cord anymore, and the problem was solved. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

I second that case about strong electromagnetic field, could be a reason to move or even relocate if your home is there.

I was visiting a cafe for coffee and work, where everything was just not right: the shaky floor, the running there and back waitresses. I changed my table for 3 times, and at the last one I started to get the errors like in the question. Then I rebooted for like 5-7 times with same result. Unable to do anything in a pretty irritated state (which is very strange for me) I went home.

At home now - everything is back to normal!

Looks like sensitive devices like SSD disk (or human body's psychoemotional state) can react to the electromagnetic environment like that.

So before doing any reconfiguration of your system or any other risky changes trying to save your laptop, try another location first!